# How to check wether a wifi network is secured or open using wpa_cli/wpa_supplicant or any other utility?

Tags: wifi, embedded-linux, wpa-supplicant

Wpa_cli command requires you to know in advance if a network is open or secured. I'm developing a script using wpa_cli and I just want it to connects to network whether it is open or secured , obviously if secured it should ask for password otherwise it should just connect.

How can I check if a network is open or secured so that scripts runs wpa_cli accordingly?

I just want a behavior like android phone, if a network is open it just connects to it, if it is secured it asks for password.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell from the probe response what security settings a network is using.

In wpa_cli you'll need to do a scan and parse the results to find the SSID you want to connect to, and there it will tell you the security settings:

```
wpa_cli scan
```

Then to see the results of the scan:

```
wpa_cli scan_results
```

There is also another command that is not related to wpa_cli. From a shell:

```
iwlist interfaceID scan
```

Where interfaceID is your wireless adapter (e.g. wlan0).

This gives you scan results but with much more detail.
Again this can be used to deduce the security settings of a network.

Comment: probably worth mentioning `iw` tool as well which can carry out scan.